# How to use caps lock as a distinct meta key in OSX?

Tags: macos, key-bindings, autohotkey

Is there a way to make use of the Caps Lock key as a *new* meta key (not mapping it to an existing key as is available in System Preferences)?

The only feature of Windows I miss on my Mac is the Autohotkey remapping of the Caps Lock key to a new meta key.  I use this as a launcher/switcher for my frequent used apps, eg.

```
SetCapsLockState, AlwaysOff

CapsLock & a::
IfWinExist jEdit
 WinActivate
else
 Run C:\PROGRA~1\jEdit\jedit.bat
return
```

Just to be clear, I'm not looking for Autohotkey on the Mac (though that would be nice).

Answer (score 1):

Answered in the KeyRemap4Macbook user group:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/keyremap4macbook/CMn9H6ALNmw

Thanks Takayama Fumihiko!